# EOleSysError with message 'Invalid number of parameters' when automating PDFCreator from Delphi app

Tags: delphi, automation, ole

I am trying to automate PDFCreator from a Delphi application with the following sample code:

```
procedure TForm13.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  PDFCreatorQueue,
  job: OleVariant;
begin
  PDFCreatorQueue := CreateOleObject('PDFCreatorBeta.JobQueue');

  if not VarIsNull(PDFCreatorQueue)then
  begin
    try
      PDFCreatorQueue.Initialize();
//
//      if not PDFCreatorQueue.WaitForJob(15) then
//        MessageDlg(SPDFCreatorTimeout, mtError, [mbOK], 0)
//      else
//      begin
//        job := PDFCreatorQueue.NextJob();
//        job.ConversionProfileByGuid := 'DefaultGuid';
//        job.ConvertTo(FilePath);
//
//        if(not job.IsJobFinished or not job.JobSucceed) then
//          MessageDlg(Format(SPDFCreatorCouldNotConvertFile, [FilePath]), mtError, [mbOK], 0);
//      end;
    finally
      PDFCreatorQueue.ReleaseCom();
    end;
  end
  else
    MessageDlg(SPDFCreatorConnectionError, mtError, [mbOK], 0);
end;
```

At the line PDFCreatorQueue.Initialize(); an exception occurs:

*EOleSysError with message 'Invalid number of parameters'*

The method Initialize on the PDFCreator side does not have any parameters:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
[Guid("66A9CAB1-404A-4918-8DE2-29C26B9B271E")]
[ProgId("PDFCreatorBeta.JobQueue")]
public class Queue : IQueue
{

...

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes the essential components like JobInfoQueue for the COM object
    /// </summary>
    public void Initialize()
    {
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have a TypeLib import unit for PDFCreator?

Comment: I don't have it, but the source code is available on the following address: http://download.pdfforge.org/download/pdfcreator/list

Comment: Sorry, I can't see any sign of source code there, only various PDFCreator and PDFCreatorBeta executables.  In any case, the TypeLib import unit is usually something you create yourself inside Delphi by running a Delphi wizard on a .TLB, .OCX, .DLL or, more rarely, an .Exe file.  I haven't been able to run the wizard (in D7 or XE6) against any of the PdfCreator 1.7* or 1.9* files, fwiw.  What is odd is that google finds a few messages from people who have succeeded, but only on earlier versions, as far as I could see.  Btw, what Delphi version are you using?

Comment: Btw, I'm not sure whether you're aware, but one of the points of producing a Delphi import unit is that it tells you the parameters expected for each class's methods.

Comment: The code shown is clearly the c# source code from some element of pdfCreator.  The only interface that pdfCreator registers is for an AxPdfReader ActiveX so this clearly isn't a standard COM interface of the package.  It looks to me as if what you should be doing is building pdfCreator and then importing the relevant dll as a .NET assembly. RAD studio menu "component\import component", select .NET assembly and then potentially add the relevant dll by direct reference.

Comment: Attribute [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)] prevents the class to be called with early binding. That is probably the reason the wizard does not create TypeLib information. The interesting problem is that in C# code there are no parameters, but when called from Delphi and exception "Invalid number of parameters" is raised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There is specific behavior of calling COM from Delphi.**

When You implement parameter less method of .net com visible assembly

```
class CShaprClass
{
  Initialize();
}
```

When You calling such parameter less method in Delphi code:

```
  PDFCreatorQueue.Initialize();
```

You will get Invalid Parameters Error. 
Delphi in this calling method transcription inform COM that will be sending parameters.

You should call

```
  PDFCreatorQueue.Initialize;
```